Curl on Ubuntu 24.04: Recv failure (35)
I am encountering issues with curl on my Ubuntu 24.04 system when trying to access HTTPS URLs. Specifically, when I run curl https://google.com, I receive the error: curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer.
I can successfully ping google.com, and when I run curl -4 https://google.com, I receive an HTML response indicating a 301 redirect to https://www.google.com/. I suspect this might be related to DNS configuration or firewall settings, but I’m not sure how to proceed.

Verified that both OpenSSL and curl are updated (OpenSSL 3.0.13 and curl 8.5.0).
Checked my /etc/resolv.conf:

# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .


Ran resolvectl status:

Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp7s0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp8s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.163.60
       DNS Servers: 192.168.163.60 2a01:5ec0:e801:c85c::18


Also tried with curl -vvv https://google.com. and the output is:

* Host google.com:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: 2001:4860:4802:32::78
* IPv4: 216.239.38.120
*   Trying [2001:4860:4802:32::78]:443...
* Connected to google.com (2001:4860:4802:32::78) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to google.com:443 
* Closing connection
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I don't know why but when I use a VPN (I used Nekoray), It works.
The output while using a VPN:
❯ curl -vvv https://google.com
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1'
* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'http://127.0.0.1:2081/'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:2081...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 2081
* CONNECT tunnel: HTTP/1.1 negotiated
* allocate connect buffer
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to google.com:443
> CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
< 
* CONNECT phase completed
* CONNECT tunnel established, response 200
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / X25519 / id-ecPublicKey
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Aug 26 06:33:47 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 18 06:33:46 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "google.com" matched cert's "google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=WR2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type EC/prime256v1 (256/128 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 1: Public key type RSA (2048/112 Bits/secBits), signed using sha256WithRSAEncryption
*   Certificate level 2: Public key type RSA (4096/152 Bits/secBits), signed using sha384WithRSAEncryption
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://google.com/
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: google.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.5.0]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
< HTTP/2 301 
< location: https://www.google.com/
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< content-security-policy-report-only: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-iuakndeP211B810I4MYmMQ' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/other-hp
< date: Wed, 25 Sep 2024 12:28:25 GMT
< expires: Fri, 25 Oct 2024 12:28:25 GMT
< cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
< server: gws
< content-length: 220
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact

Os: Ubuntu v24.04

Please edit the verbose output of curl into your question (curl -vvv https://google.com)

@GeraldSchneider Added.
